# Retrieve O365 SharePoint lists from Cordova hybrid mobile app

Tags: cordova, sharepoint, office365, office365-apps, office365api

I have scoured the web looking for a way to retrieve SharePoint Online lists inside a Cordova hybrid app in Visual Studio 2015. I've found many samples for reading/writing to my Calendar ([Woodgrove Demo](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Woodgrove-Demo-for-Tools-ebcfdda5)) and retrieving my contacts ([Cordova Contact App Sample](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Cordova-Contact-App-Code-Sample)) and they all worked well and helped me learn how to get past the authentication step.

Now I am looking for a way to bring down some SharePoint list data and display it in my app. I haven't been able to find a straightforward explanation or demonstration of how to do this. Is there anyone out there who has done this or can point me to a sample app that does this? I am a newby at O365 development, am I looking to use the O365 api to retrieve the list data or the REST api or something different all together?

I would greatly appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some [sample apps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/howto/starter-projects-and-code-samples) for building on the Office 365 API.  This [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Dn848423.aspx) is a quick example of getting SharePoint files.

This is the [best example](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ocarpen/archive/2015/03/22/sharepoint-online-apache-cordova-et-winjs-creer-des-apps-mobiles-d-entreprise-multi-devices.aspx) I've seen on how to add a connected service to your cordova app for SharePoint Online.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Emmie, but that article is for building a "SharePoint Add-in". I'm looking for a resource on building a Cordova hybrid mobile app that can take in SharePoint lists and libraries.

Comment: Emmie, you rock. That was exactly what I was looking for and Google failed me!

Comment: Great!  Glad I can help!